# Pandas dataframe, check list in column an set value in different column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I need your help for the following task:
I have the following dataframe:

```
test = {'Col1':[2,5],
        'Col2':[5,7],
        'Col_List':[['One','Two','Three','Four','Five'], ['Two', 'Four']],
       'One':[0,0],
       'Two':[0,0],
       'Three':[0,0],
       'Four':[0,0],
       'Five':[0,0],}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test)
df
```

which looks like:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col_List | One | Two | Three | Four | Five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | [One, Two, Three, Four, Five] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 7 | [Two, Four] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I need to inspect the list in `Col_List` and set, depending on which item is in the list, the value of column `Col1` in the specific column (`One`, `Two`, `Three`, `Four` or `Five`).

Now I would like to have the following result:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col_List | One | Two | Three | Four | Five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | [One, Two, Three, Four, Five] | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 7 | [Two, Four] | 0 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
exploded = df.explode("Col_List")

df.update(pd.get_dummies(exploded["Col_List"])
            .mul(exploded["Col1"], axis="rows")
            .groupby(level=0).sum())
```

- explode lists' elements to their own rows
- get 1-hot representation of "One", "Two" etc.
- multiply it with the (exploded) "Col1" values

  - 1/0 values will act as a selector
- then undo the explosion: groupby & sum
- lastly update the original frame's "One", "Two"... columns with this

to get

```py
>>> df

   Col1  Col2                       Col_List  One  Two  Three  Four  Five
0     2     5  [One, Two, Three, Four, Five]    2    2      2     2     2
1     5     7                    [Two, Four]    0    5      0     5     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try explode the data, unstack it, then assign back:

```
s = (df[['Col1', 'Col_List']].explode('Col_List')
   .set_index('Col_List', append=True)['Col1']
   .unstack().fillna(df)
)

df.loc[s.index, s.columns] = s
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2                       Col_List  One  Two  Three  Four  Five
0     2     5  [One, Two, Three, Four, Five]  2.0  2.0    2.0   2.0   2.0
1     5     7                    [Two, Four]  0.0  5.0    0.0   5.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
aux = df.explode('Col_List')
df.update(pd.crosstab(aux.index, aux['Col_List'], aux['Col1'],
    aggfunc=lambda x: x))
```

---

Alternatively, using [`numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
colnames = df.loc[:, 'One':'Five'].columns
df[colnames] = (df['Col1'].values[:, None] * np.vstack([np.any(colnames.values ==
                np.array(x)[:, None], axis=0) for x in df['Col_List']]))
```

---

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2                       Col_List  One  Two  Three  Four  Five
0     2     5  [One, Two, Three, Four, Five]    2    2      2     2     2
1     5     7                    [Two, Four]    0    5      0     5     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.str.join()` and `str.get_dummies()`

```
df.assign(**df['Col_List'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies().mul(df['Col1'],axis=0))
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2                       Col_List  One  Two  Three  Four  Five
0     2     5  [One, Two, Three, Four, Five]    2    2      2     2     2
1     5     7                    [Two, Four]    0    5      0     5     0
```